# How to make XmlnsDefinition work on the local assembly?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've started using the XmlnsDefinition attribute to tie together some CLR namespaces into a single xmlns for convenience in XAML.

Unfortunately, it seems that this only works when using foreign assemblies. If I have a XAML file in the same assembly as the types that are in the namespace I'm referencing from XmlnsDefinition, then the compiler gives an error about the type not existing in the xmlns I am defining.

Moving the type to a foreign assembly fixes the problem.

Is there a way to use XmlnsDefinition on an assembly and have it be used from within that assembly via XAML?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The XAML file must be parsed before the assembly is built in order to generate the code implied by the XAML to be included in the assembly. The XAML compiler produces code behind files (the files ending in, for example, .g.cs) and these file then become part of the assembly the XAML file is contained in. Since the assembly hasn't been built yet, the XAML compiler cannot load it to determine XmlnsDeclaration attributes have been specified.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me. How does XAML compiler knows how to use custom classes when you reference them in XAML? Isn't it the same thing, those classes are within same assembly, how come XAML compiler can find those but not the XmlnsDefinition attributes?

Answer (score -1):

Use `clr-namespace` instead. For example:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Rhapsody.UI.Main.Controls
```

Comment: This will be very troublesome when you define different namespaces in your project for storing Converters, Selectors, Commands. You must define `xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Project.Converters"`,  `xmlns:s="clr-namespace:Project.Selectors"`,  `xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:Project.Commands"` every time when you use them in each class.