# WPF Custom Namespaces not working

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, xml-namespaces

I follow this [Guide in codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111911/A-Guide-to-Cleaner-XAML-with-Custom-Namespaces-and).

So, I add this to the AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: XmlnsPrefix("http://my-project.com/wpf", "g")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://my-project.com/wpf", "GUI.View.Result")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://my-project.com/wpf", "GUI.ViewModel.Result")]
```

Then I use it like this in xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:g="http://my-project.com/wpf">


    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type g:ResultListViewModel}">
        <g:ResultListView/>
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

I have the following errors:

> The name "ResultListView" does not exist in the namespace
>   "http://my-project.com/wpf"
>
> The name "ResultListViewModel" does not exist in the namespace
>   "http://my-project.com/wpf"

Am I doing something wrong.
This is not a reference to another project, all this code are in the same VS2012 project.

Any idea? Please?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried 1. Rebuilding and 2. Restarting VS?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2760504/643085. `XmlnsDefinition` only works for namespaces in other assemblies, not in the same assembly.

Comment: Thanks! That question has exactly the same situation. sorry about that...

Answer (score 4):

XML namespace mappings often do not work in XAML files within the same assembly declaring the mapping.  Within that assembly, you will usually have to use the `clr-namespace` URIs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there any specific reason for this?

Comment: Not sure exactly.  I’m sure it could be *made to work*, but for whatever reason the team behind VS chose not to.  Perhaps it was much more complicated to analyze assembly-level attributes on possibly uncomplicated code prior to Roslyn?