# Custom xmlns namespaces not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590031/tabitem-in-a-separate-xaml) for separating tab content into separate files. Here is my file structure
[image: TabAttributesContext.xaml in TabContext folder with MainWindow.xaml]

I am trying to load file **2**'s content with file **1** so that they work together. Here is file 2:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <UserControl x:Key="Tab1Control">
        <DataTemplate DataType="TabItem">
            <TextBlock Text="Test text"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And the relevant portion of file 1:

```
<Window x:Class="MnMCharacterCreator.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:tabs="TabContent/TabAttributesContent">
        ...
    <!--Creates a tabbing system, with a grid defined by each ItemsControl-->
    <TabControl Name="WindowTabs">
        <TabItem Name="WindowTab1" Header="Attributes">
            <!--This is where the UserControl from file 2 should be loaded-->
```

After visiting [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522258/wpf-custom-namespaces-not-working) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760504/how-to-make-xmlnsdefinition-work-on-the-local-assembly) related questions (with tens of others) and asking on C# chat, I'm left thinking that this is unusual:

[image: tabs is not supported in a WPF project error message]

Intellisense shows nothing for `<tabs:` and even if I manually type an existing name or something, an error message is given, meaning that it is not a designer issue. [Here](http://www.filetolink.com/29491be36d) is the full solution in VS2012.

To be specific, the question I am trying to ask is **how can I use content from another xaml file?** If `xmlns` isn't possible, what is?

Comment: A data template inside a usercontrol? I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. but at the same time `2` is a resource dictionary so you may not see anything with `tabs:` but you may access this way `{StaticResource Tab1Control}` or in markup like `<StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="Tab1Control" />`.

Comment: @pushpraj but as I'm trying to load XAML content, then unless there's a `content=` property I'm unaware of, I can't use it like a resource.

Comment: what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @pushpraj I need to use the content from another xaml file, as the question asks, and in the context of splitting xaml files so that I have a separate xaml file per tab item, as declared at the top. Anything that allows me to place the content of each tab item in their appropriate places during run-time while keeping them separated into different files during design time is what I'm asking for.

Comment: It may be worth noting that a very surprising number of users have responded with my idea of separating xaml files with "why do that?" Well, imagine 10,000 lines of XAML in one file. That's *not* how large applications do that and I need this application to be configured for flexibility. I'm just saying this ahead of time.

Comment: great! but before I may answer your question, could you give me what kind of data you have? are you using any MVVM pattern? a sample close to what you actually have would be appreciated.

Comment: @pushpraj I *think* I'm using MVVM because it's complicated and hard to understand. The samples I posted above are what I have. I also uploaded my entire solution to look at when I created this question. You can find the link just above the bolded question text. It's small.

Comment: The referenced question puts `TabItem`s in a `TabControl` not at `TabItem`.  You're not defining any TabItem user controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to create a user  control for tab item as ,

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFSample.TabItem1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Height="100" Width="100" Text="Hi from tab item 1"/>
</Grid>
```

Then for using  this add the namespace in the MainWindow as :

```
<Window x:Class="WPFSample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFSample">
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="XYZ">
            <local:TabItem1/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

You are ready to use .

Hope you have changed the usercontrol xaml.cs from XYZ : Window to XYZ : UserControl and build the solution once .