# How can I move something to "another assembly"?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-assembly, xml-namespaces

The situation I am encountering is the same as here:

[WPF Custom Namespaces not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522258/wpf-custom-namespaces-not-working)

> XmlnsDefinition only works for namespaces in other assemblies, not in
>   the same assembly.

However, I don't really get what is exactly meant by "same assembly" and "different assembly". If AssemblyInfo.cs and the XAML files are in the same assembly, how can I move AssemblyInfo.cs away from the assembly to another?

Answer (score 1):

Documentation does not refer to such any limitation.

> **Mapping CLR Namespaces to XML Namespaces in an Assembly**
>
> WPF defines a CLR attribute that is consumed by XAML processors in order to map multiple CLR namespaces to a single XAML namespace. This attribute, [XmlnsDefinitionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute), is placed at the assembly level in the source code that produces the assembly. The WPF assembly source code uses this attribute to map the various common namespaces, such as [System.Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows) and [System.Windows.Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls), to the http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation namespace.
>
> The [XmlnsDefinitionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute) takes two parameters: the XML/XAML namespace name, and the CLR namespace name. More than one [XmlnsDefinitionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute) can exist to map multiple CLR namespaces to the same XML namespace. Once mapped, members of those namespaces can also be referenced without full qualification if desired by providing the appropriate using statement in the partial-class code-behind page. For more details, see [XmlnsDefinitionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping-for-wpf-xaml#mapping-clr-namespaces-to-xml-namespaces-in-an-assembly

Comment: I don't get it. I have found many sources from the Internet telling that `XmlnsDefinition` does not work in the same assembly. If it's not true, what is the explanation to the situation like the question I quoted?

Comment: I think chuckj's explanation can clear things for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/2778489/3445247

Comment: His explanation is for the point "`XmlnsDefinition` cannot work for namespaces in the same assembly". Now back to my question, how can I move AssemblyInfo.cs to another assembly to solve it?

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Each assembly may have its own `AssemblyInfo` class. What is it that you are trying to "move"?

Comment: To tie the namespaces into one, which is the same as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2778489/3445247), but the "same assembly" issue seems to prevent me from doing this.

Comment: "Moving the type to a foreign assembly fixes the problem." from the above link. How to do that?