# preprocessor in xaml file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight

i am currently changing my project from silverlight to wpf. so i was thinking if i could do something like this then would not have to make a copy of all my xaml files. i could just link them to the old files

in xaml file ,i would like something like this:

```
#IF Silverligtht
xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows"
#elif
xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=PresentationFramework"
#endif
```

I would prefer not to change the code behind files for this xaml. But if that the only solution then please let me know of that.

I tried to do some research but could not find a helpful topic. This was something i thought might be helpful but cant really understand how to use this:

http://blog.ikaika.org/2011/08/run-time-and-design-time-selection-of.html

EDIT:

Visual studio wont let me do something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="debug-mode"


    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"

    <mc:AlternateContent>
<mc:Choice Requires="d">
    xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=PresentationFramework"
</mc:Choice>
<mc:Fallback>
    xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=PresentationFramework"
</mc:Fallback>
</mc:AlternateContent>

>
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

Edit2:
i Guess this is what you are saying:

i added this to the AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("debug", "System.Windows")]
```

And i made my MainWindow.xaml to look like this, just to try stuff:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:dd="debug"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <dd:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <dd:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">

            <dd:VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="GradiantOverlay"
                                        BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                        Duration="00:00:00.50"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                        FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                        <LinearColorKeyFrame 
                                            Value="#40000000" 
                                            KeyTime="00:00:00.50"/>
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="GradiantOverlay"
                                        BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                        Duration="00:00:00.50"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                        FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                        <LinearColorKeyFrame 
                                            Value="#5E000000" 
                                            KeyTime="00:00:00.50"/>
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="GradiantOverlay"
                                        BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                        Duration="00:00:00.50"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                        FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                        <LinearColorKeyFrame 
                                            Value="#00000000" 
                                            KeyTime="00:00:00.50"/>
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="GradiantGloss"
                                        BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                        Duration="00:00:00.50"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                        FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                        <LinearColorKeyFrame 
                                            Value="#48FFFFFF" 
                                            KeyTime="00:00:00.50"/>
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="GradiantGloss"
                                        BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                        Duration="00:00:00.50"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                        FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                        <LinearColorKeyFrame 
                                            Value="#CEFFFFFF" 
                                            KeyTime="00:00:00.50"/>
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </dd:VisualState>
        </dd:VisualStateGroup>
    </dd:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

i got this as the compile time error:

> Error 1   The tag 'VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups' does not exist in XML namespace 'debug'. Line 8 Position 10. c:\users\sahluwai\documents\visual studio 2013\Projectsaa\WpfApplication4\WpfApplication4\MainWindow.xaml   8   10  WpfApplication4

Comment: The marked duplicate should address your question exactly. I will note, however, that my experience using this technique has been that the Visual Studio editor doesn't understand the markup very well, and you wind up with a lot of spurious warnings and errors at design-time. They don't affect the ability to build the project, but they are annoying.  I generally stick with run-time solutions, even though they often involve superfluous XAML/resource objects (since the underlying selection is still compile-time, you wind up with unused code/data)

Comment: @PeterDuniho i just tried to use the bj0 answer on [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732307/does-xaml-have-a-conditional-compiler-directive-for-debug-mode) .But i guess because of some reason , from the statement ` xmlns:d="debug-mode" ` , The d is not getting defined, Hence it always uses the fallback code.

Comment: Because you are trying to conditionally declare the XML namespace itself, the part of the marked answer that is important is the `[assembly: XmlnsDefinition( "debug-mode", "Namespace" )]`. I.e. you don't need to use the markup-compatibility namespace; you just need to conditionally declare a namespace in Assembly.cs and refer to it in the `xmlns:vsm` attribute.

Comment: @PeterDuniho please let me know your response to edit in the question

Comment: @RonBeyer please let me know your response to edit in the question

Comment: I have already responded to your edit. See my comment above.

Comment: @PeterDuniho please let me know what you think about edit 2 . Tried to implement what you were saying

Comment: Are you trying to define the `[XmlnsDefinition]` in the same assembly where you are using it? If so, [that won't work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2778489). That said, it's not clear to me why you need to declare this particular one at all; VisualStateManager is already in the default `http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation` namespace, and I suspect the Silverlight one too. Conditional-compilation of XAML is well-answered already on SO, but it might be you should be thinking more broadly and asking for help for whatever larger issue is at work here.